# Writing and routing over ethernet without IP

Tags: python, networking, routes, ip, ethernet

I have a project in which I need to setup a network that is essentially a bunch of Raspberry Pis connected through a router over ethernet, and have them talk to each other without using IP.

My challenge here is two folds, first, how can I write raw binary data to ethernet to pass my own custom payloads and have a custom parser on each end picking up and deserialising that data?

Second, and this is secondary for this post, if anyone has any ideas as to how I could use a router without using IP (aka setting up my own simple addressing protocol) this would be very welcomed. So far what I've sketched out is to procure myself a router than can be flashed, then have custom software on there running a custom protocol. However I'm not sure if this is even doable with off the shelf routers. Pointers are welcome.

Ideally I'd like to do all of this in python.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question: [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio-streams) comes as a standard library with Python. It can handle most of your communication needs, essentially acting as your communication stream for your binary data. Example implementation [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366134/can-someone-implement-a-custom-network-protocol).

For your second question: you can't go wrong with using IPv4. You could potentially implement something new but you'd probably go down a [rabbit hole](https://beenje.github.io/blog/posts/experimenting-with-asyncio-on-a-raspberry-pi/) in doing so.

Comment: I specifically want to avoid using IP.

Comment: If you need to route (=forward between layer-2 networks) you do require a network-layer protocol and a router using it. You'd have to re-implement large portions of IP in order to do so.